# Histogram/binning data

Tags: statistics

According to a task we are supposed to bin data as follows:

(1) 2001 (?) bins for the range from -1 to 1 in steps of 0.01

(2) 33 bins for the range 0 to 160 in steps of 5

I am not sure though, if the task is not possed faulty? The 2001 should be probably 201.
And then I was wondering how I split up the datapoints best: The range 0 to 160 obviously contains 161 integers, so if I split it up into bins of [0-5), [5-10)...then I would have 160 left in one bin alone - so what would I do?

Comment: Yes. I believe the 2001 is a typo. It should either be 201, or the step should be 0.001.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The choice is up to you.

Suppose you have to bin 0 to 3 in steps of 1.
Then there are 3 common ways to do so:

1. [0,1) [1,2) [2,3) [3, $\infty$)
2. [0,1) [1,2) [2,3]
3. [$-\frac 12,\frac 12$) [$\frac 12,\frac 32$) [$\frac 32,\frac 52$) [$\frac 52,\frac 72$)

The first option is good if you have data that is not necessarily bounded. This is what Excel does.

The second option gets rid of the top value without unnecessarily introducing a new bin. In your case it is not an option, since you would get the wrong number of bins.

The third way is a good option if you expect the numbers to be close to integer values, or if you want rounded integer values as output.

They are all good and valid ways to bin.

Comment: So, for 0 to 160, how can I now which intervals to take to end up with 33 bins? One option e.g. would be [-2,2), [3,7), [7,11) according to your point 3., but how would I calculate the number of bins I get?

Comment: I would pick [$-2\frac 12, 2\frac 12$), [$2\frac 12, 7\frac 12$), ... Now suppose the range were 0 to 15 with steps of 5. Then you would get 4 bins right? This is equal to $\frac{15-0}{5} + 1$. What does that make for the range 0 to 160?

Comment: Yes, this is well understandlble, I would get 33 bins. Another question: I do understand that data can be represented in different but all correct ways, but the histogram I get is different when I go with the last bin over the biggest element, does that not lead to a skewed perspective?

Comment: Yes. The histograms will be different. Whatever you do, at least one bin will be skewed. When interpreting a histogram, this is always something that has to be taken into consideration.